Interpretation of parallel transport over a triangle in a sphere
I'm doing the parallel transport as indicated in this Wikipedia article. I'm using the ideas for the rectangle case in this other article.
My problem is that given that the top of the triangle is at the origin. The resulting transport is just $$\delta V^\alpha = - \delta b \Gamma^\beta_{b \mu} A^{\mu}$$
If the top was not on the origin then it would be:
$$\delta V^\alpha =  \delta b [ \delta a (\partial_b \Gamma^\beta_{a \mu} A^\mu - \partial_a \Gamma^\beta_{b \mu} A^\mu) - \Gamma^\beta_{b \mu} A^{\mu}]$$
I don't understand how it affects so much the fact that it's on the origin. Is my deduction right or am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Why all these formulas? If you’re working with a geodesic triangle, you can do this all completely conceptually. Regardless, please make your question self-contained and understandable.
